# Detect hyperlink when link is clicked without link id or class in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, joomla2.5

I need to show an alert, when the hyperlink is clicked without using the hyperlink id or class name or function in the hyperlink button or text. So i need to alert for every hyperlink in particular web page.

Comment: i think we have to guess for what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector for the `a` element (using jQuery), like so:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
  alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript (as the question doesn't mention jQuery at all), you could use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // get all <a> elements on the page
for(var i=0; i< anchors.length; i++){ // for each one
  anchors[i].onclick = function(){  // if clicked
    alert("All anchors will trigger this on click"); // alert
  }  
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/72wN4/)

Answer (score 1):

With jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(e){
     alert($(this).attr("href"));
})
```

This will work on dinamicaly created links too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $("a").on('click', function() { 
      alert("Hello");
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("a").click(function() {
      alert('............');
    });

});
```

Comment: Use `on` if you need it to work for dynamically created links.